# AQTime DLL profiling - no results

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, profiler, aqtime

I am trying to profile memory allocation in a DLL, say pluginDLL.dll. I create a new project in AQTime and add the module 'pluginDLL.dll'. This DLL is compiled in Release x64 with VisualStudio 10, all my projects are C++. This DLL is linked to a lib. Say algo.lib. I add to the AQTime project the DLL algo.dll.

pluginDLL.dll is a DLL programmed on an API to an application, say MainApp.exe. If I launch MainApp.exe, then open my plugin, the process MainAppSDK starts. This process starts when any plugin written with this SDK starts.

So, to run the profiling, I proceed as follows (I have already created the project with the two DLLs): I launch manually MainApp.exe. I open manually my plugin, so that MainAppSDK process starts. In AQTime, I attach the process MainAppSDK, and runs the profiling.

If I check Check Memory Bounds, application crashes. Warnings in Event pane are of type 'Access violation' in some msvcr100.dll.

If i check two other options only, i can run my plugin to the end. I can read messages from my application in the event pane, stating that application ran to the end successfully. Before it ends, I click the camera to get the results. And then results are generated but are empty...

Could you help me troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting you profiling using the approach described in the [Profiling Multiple Processes](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/43332/) help topic instead of just attaching to the running process.

If this does not help, try using the [online AQtime Troubleshooter](http://support.smartbear.com/troubleshooter/?prod=AQtime).